# How to efficiently import many large JSON files directly from S3 into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

I have compressed JSON files in S3 and I would like to set up MongoDB in EC2 to server json documents contained in these files. The compressed files are >100M and there are 1000s of them. Each file contains 100000s of small documents.

What is the best way to get this data into Mongo?
It would be nicest if there was a way to give Mongo the S3 paths
and have it retrieve them itself.
I there anything better than downloading the data to the server and doing mongoimport?

Also how well Mongo handle this amount of data?

Comment: Seems like writing a script to use mongoimport would be the most effective.

Comment: A script automates the process, but does not help with the extra local storage required or the copying time.

Comment: why can't you stream uncompressed data directly to mongoimport? why would they have to be stored uncompressed on disk?

Comment: @Asya Kamsky, that is the kind of thing I am looking for. What are the commands to do that. s3cm commands want to create files for the files they download & mongimport seems to want a file as input. I tried using /dev/stdin & /dev/stdout to get around that, but it did not work.

Comment: mongoimport does not want a file - you can stream stdout to it via | for example, if you have a gz file you can do 'zcat file.gz | mongoimport' but I don't know what s3 options you have.

Comment: Thanks @AsyaKamsky! I did not realize that either s3cmd or mongoimport supported IO redirection. Problem solved.

Comment: posted summary as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to store intermediate files, you can pipe the output of s3 file to stdout and you can get input to `mongoimport` from stdin.

Your full command would look something like:

```
s3cmd get s3://<yourFilename> - | mongoimport -d <dbName> -c <collectionName>
```

note the `-` which says send the file to `stdout` rather than to a filename.

Comment: I just have one file whose output I want to use.  But when using this method, I am not able to get the solution.

Comment: no way to know why you can't since you don't provide any information. Best to start a new question, or discussion on MongoDB-user Google Group.

Comment: if someone is wondering to do this using aws cli : `aws s3 cp s3://<fileURI> - | mongoimport --db <dbname>--collection <collectionName>`

Answer (score 0):

The alternative of using `s3cmd` is to use `aws s3` which has fewer features but comes installed with AWS CLI.

The command would look like:

```
aws S3 cp <your s3 URI> - | \
mongoimport \
--db <dbName> \
--collection <collectionName> \
```

The `-` sends the file to `stdout`