# Not able to read a large JSON file in memory from Amazon S3 in Jackson ArrayNode using Jackson

Tags: java, json, amazon-s3, jackson

I am trying to read a very large JSON file which is stored on Amazon S3 and contains around 30,000 records and is of size 100 MB.

I am trying to reads all the records in JSON ArrayNode in Java. I am not able to read all the records in memory. It reads upto 3619 records and then my server restarts. I am not able to find any log traces of this problem in logs too.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: try look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971851/how-to-efficiently-import-many-large-json-files-directly-from-s3-into-mongodb

Comment: Can you do it with GSON?

Answer (score -1):

Please download the file from S3 using the S3 console, and then modify this perl script as appropriate to see if the data you have downloaded is actually valid Json:

```
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use strict;
use Carp;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use JSON;

my $File = "....";       # File name containing downloaded JSON
open(my $f, "<$File") or die "Cannot open file $File for input";
local $/;                # Enable localized slurp mode
my $j = <$f>;
my $d = decode_json $j;

print dump($d);
```